# What resources would be depleted during a “Medieval Stasis”?

Tags: science-based, materials

Many fantasy worlds use a [“Medieval Stasis”](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MedievalStasis)trope. What resources could we expect to become depleted during a stasis? Surely, since technology is stagnant, the people would mine all the materials they could reach and exploit whatever they could. Smelting and recycling isn’t a perfect process with medieval technology. There is often wasted/ruined material.

What resources can we expect will be depleted and on what timescales? Let’s base this off of a 200AD Roman Empire for our technology basis.

Comment: Unfortunately the only way to find out is to go through such an stasis.

Comment: There is nowhere near enough data ot answer this question.  What geographic area are we talking about?  What is the population?  Over what range should the resource depletion be analyzed?  Note that if we take 200AD Rome as the focal point in all aspects, the answer is "practically infinite."  There wasn't enough people or industry to deplete anything other than forests.

Comment: Stasis implies infinite years. Many fantasy worlds have “histories” that span hundreds of thousands of years.

Comment: The medieval period was one of continual advancement, largely driven by depletion of ready to access resources, in particular energy. The discovery of an effective way to burn coal marks the transition between medieval and Renaissance periods.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- **Soil**
  Depending on the agricultural methods (lack of crop rotation, etc.) the quality of over-used fields might go down. Especially if the population density is too high to give them time to recover. Slopes are getting farmed, grass cover is plowed under, rain causes [gullies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gully), the topsoil erodes.
- **Wood**
  The use of firewood, building timber, and charcoal exceeds the regeneration capacity of the forests. There was significant [deforestation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deforestation_during_the_Roman_period) during Roman times. Some time later, the [Royal Navy](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/1012795.pdf) had problems to find timber.
- **Fish**
  Probably not on the high seas, but overfishing can be an issue in lakes or rivers.
- **Circus Animals**
  Not a critical resource, but Europe ran out of [lions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_lions_in_Europe) during historical ages. It is unclear how much that was the *use* of lions for entertainment purposes or the *extermination* of lions for livestock protection.

Comment: Good answer. The drive for resources was what led to the innovations that mark the boundary with the Renaissance.

Comment: Perhaps a section on metals might be relevant? Medieval technology would only allow the exploitation of relatively easy deposits. Once these deposits are mined the only sources will be recycling. Due to slag waste of medieval smelting I’d imagine that on a long enough timescale many metals could grow scarce

Comment: @Hippeus_Lancer Yeah. Iron is extremely plentiful but running out of the most dense concentrations of it would require innovation (in feudal Japan they used iron sands and ingots were very precious). Running out of either copper or tin would make bronze production impossible, for what that's worth. Mining and then running out or gold or silver could force an economic readjustment.

Comment: Also: It's sort of covered by "circus animals" but certain practical beasts like Elephants might end up extinct in the wild/in general. Much like fish, game such as boars, stag, and aurauchs can only handle so much hunting. You would also most certainly see social depletions where slave economies run out of dominions, land holdings get split up too many times among heirs, or wealth consolidation becomes too great to sustain the particular organization of your society.

Comment: @Hippeus_Lancer, I wonder how long that can be overcome by digging *just a little bit* deeper, without a fundamental change in technologies (like steam pumps).

Comment: @o.m, I was thinking that a limit will be reached eventually. You can only pump so much water with archimedes screw pumps out of a mine. Maybe the better option would be strip mining/hydraulic mining like the Romans did in spain. Even then a limit will be reached where the hole is too deep to make removing overburden worth it.

Comment: @Hippeus_Lancer, that depends very much on the geology, I think. Medieval people used less than one percent per capita per year of modern requirements, and they had lower populations. An amount that would last for a year today would last for a millenium.

Comment: To add to @Ekrie in England there were many large animals,that were hunted to extinction during the medieval period. Bears in the 9-10th century, boars in the  14-15th and wolves around the same time. The geography restrictions on the movement of animals lead to greater pressure on populations than ten rest of Europe, but the longer medieval period adds more time.

Comment: These are short-term issues certainly, but soil enrichment would be developed just as it had in history (crop rotation, natural fertilizers, and creation of terra preta in the Americas - these arise out of necessity), wood became tightly controlled in many areas with the people strictly limited in the amount and kind of wood they were allowed to harvest for this reason, and while small lakes and rivers could be overfished, those could be farmed (deliberately stocking lakes was not unknown) and overfishing the sea is beyond their technology. These were known issues by 200 CE.

Comment: @pluckedkiwi, would that still be *medieval stasis* as required by the OP or would that be a technological advance?

Comment: @o.m. Those have been used since antiquity - nothing new even from the perspective of 200CE. That they were not actively in use in many areas speaks more to the lack of need or cultural differences, not that these represent any kind of advance. The Greeks had been lamenting deforestation and poor soils needing management for hundreds of years at that point (they learned the hard way), and fish farms had been around the Mediterranean for much longer. While we refined some concepts over time, the basics have been around for far longer than most people realize.

Answer (score 8):

There is something paradoxical about the idea of a stasis with resource depletion, because the pre-depleted stages of the "stasis" must be quite different from the post-depleted stages. Here are some things that would run out quite fast: copper, tin, silver and gold deposits that could be exploited with medieval technology. Recycling of these metals would be feasible, but there would always be losses, which would over time exceed newly smelted replacements. I would think that in late-stasis, non-ferrous metals would be much more rare and valuable than early on. Also, deposits of unusual stone - like the white marble worked by Michelangelo - would become depleted. Also, even primitive humans were responsible for the extinction of many animals, and it's quite believable that a continent like Europe could be entirely without predators like wolves and bears if it got stuck in a long medieval phase.

The fact that even the Romans could achieve significant deforestation and overfishing tells me that this would be a serious concern. This means that any believable stasis would include periods of environmental recovery. In Europe, plagues and barbarian victories allowed some of this recovery, and we might think of other means of periodic massive human dieoffs that allow for environmental resets. Each phase of recovery would be a bit harder than the last, because of the resource depletion.

A less obvious enemy of stasis is the domestication of wild species, which wouldn't backslide in crises, and would produce increasingly useful crops and farm animals. This would gradually increase the efficiency of agriculture and allow for greater population density over time.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  This was a good first answer.  Cheers!